# Stopping a specific spark action

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Say I have a Spark job that does

```
val df1 = spark.read.csv(file1)
val df2 = spark.read.csv(file1)

df1.filter(...).join(df2, df1('id') === df1('fkey'),"inner"))
```

I know that I could stop the job with `spark.stop()` but is it possible to pause such a Spark job on a given action, say file read df1, and later resume?

Comment: Spark execution model is known as "lazy", which means it won't start reading, transforming, joining dfs until you call one of the actions. Can you clarify your problem a bit?

Comment: yeah I know lazy, assume it did start the execution and it is at some stage, say it is reading data into 3 partitions, now the question is it possible to stop this and resume it exactly at this same place. I guess I could try leverage snapshots for this.

Comment: I see... Although `SparkContext` provides methods to `cancelJob`, job group or stage (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#cancelJob-int-), I am not aware of a pause/resume notion in Spark.

Comment: thanks for the link, it seems there is an API to cancel a stage, will give it a try